# error invalid controller specified in zend framework after upload to another folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, hosting

My problem is, when i upload my project into hosting:

```
http://172.20.30.43/psm/CB11011/
```

i got this error

```
An error occurred

Page not found

Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (psm)
```

this is my full domain link..

```
http://172.20.30.43/psm/CB11011/carrental/public/user/register
```

But if i access in localhost,it look fine. This is my url for localhost..

```
localhost/carrental/public/register
```

The true controller is "register", not the psm.. for the base url i already add a line into application.ini, this is my code :

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://172.20.30.43/psm/CB11011/carrental/public/"
```

the problem path for css,js or another include file in layout.phtml look fine. They can link to right path, the only error is zend framework wrong pick my controller.. what should i do guys?? 
i'm sorry for my explaination, i'am new with zend framework, Don't know how to explain well using term in zend framework.. this is my first project using zend framework.

Comment: Why is there a dot after `register` in your URI?

Comment: oppss sorry simplyray,just typo..i will remove that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your application is in an subfolder in your hosting environment. This way zend thinks (with this call `http://172.20.30.43/psm/CB11011/`) that it should access the controller `psm` and call the action `CB11011`. Simply change your `.htaccess` file inside you `/public` directory.

Something like this (untested!!!) should be fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) ./psm/CB11011/$1
```

And change the path to the frontcontroller inside your `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/psm/CB11011"
```

---

PS: There a some security concerns about putting the whole application into a subfolder, since your controller/modules might be accessible!

Comment: Not working. i try to modified like this.. RewriteRule (.*) ./172.20.30.43psm/CB11011/$1 ..but also not working..

Comment: have you set a correct baseurl to your frontcontroller? see my edit

Comment: have improvement, but it capture wrong controller.. Invalid controller specified (carrental)..

Answer (score 0):

Try just inserting the following:

```
RewriteBase /psm/CB11011
```

into your .htaccess file, where psm/CB11011 is the subdirectory you moved the application to.